# Using pd.to_dict, get list of dict with column key/value pair which has duplicate index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data-frame with multi-index, I need to format it to list of `dict` using `pd.to_dict` or any other function

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,0,1,1], data={('c', 'a'):[10,15, 20, 50], ('c', 'b'):[15,25, 20, 30]})

    c    
    a   b
0  10  15
0  15  25
1  20  20
1  50  30
```

Excepted output:

```
{0: [{(c,a):10, (c,b):15}, {(c,a):15, (c,b):25}], 1: [{(c,a):20, (c,b):20}, {(c,a):50, (c,b):30}]}
```

Is there any optimal way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for each unique value in the index using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```
my_dict = {i : group.to_dict('records') for i, group in df.groupby(level=0)}
```

**Output**

```
{0: [{('c', 'a'): 10, ('c', 'b'): 15}, {('c', 'a'): 15, ('c', 'b'): 25}],
 1: [{('c', 'a'): 20, ('c', 'b'): 20}, {('c', 'a'): 50, ('c', 'b'): 30}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would group by index as outer loop and then use iterrows on each group

```
{idx: [v.to_dict() for _, v in grp.iterrows()] for idx, grp in df.groupby(level=0)}
```

The `level=0` is used to reference the unnamed index level

Comment: isn't `[v.to_dict() for k,v in grp.iterrows()]` equal to `grp.to_dict('records')`?